# Ionic2 Text to speech is not able to stop voice in iPhone device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, text-to-speech

I have implemented Text to speech functionality in my `ionic2` code.

I am not able to stop the current tts in iPhone device.

I have used following code :

> this.tts.speak("").then((value) => {
>               console.log('tts stopped !!! ');
>           });

The above code has stopped the current tts in android but can't able to stop in iPhone.

I have also used

> tts.stop()

method for stop current speech, but still not stopped.

Source : [Text to speech](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/text-to-speech/)

This is only not working in iPhone.

Please suggest for any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To stop any current TTS playback you can follow this example:

```
this.tts.speak("").then( _=> {
 this.tts.stop();
 console.log('tts stopped !!! ');
 });
```

#### Edit

If you want to stop it in any time, just create a function to do that:

```
<button ion-button (click)="stopTTS()">Stop TTS</button>
```

In TS:

```
stopTTS() {
 if (!!this.tts) this.tts.stop(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @melchia !!

I tried this in my code. But tts stop method not working in iPhone device. The tts speak method is first complete then stops. I want to stop it any time.